# How to initialize Java objects from a ruby script being executed by ScriptingContainer in JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Java code executing a Ruby script:

```
ruby = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
ruby.put("MyJavaClass", MyJavaClass.class);
ruby.runScriptlet(readFile("Test.rb"));
```

`MyJavaClass` code:

```
public class MyJavaClass {
    public MyJavaClass(String name) {
        System.out.println("I got a name: " + name);
    }
}
```

Ruby code within `Test.rb`:

```
someInstance = MyJavaClass.new("Joe")
```

This is what I tried to initialize a Java object within a Ruby script using JRuby. It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that by putting `MyJavaClass.class` as a ruby variable, the Java Class object available is made available to your JRuby script.  The following works:

```
java_class = MyJavaClass.getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.String.java_class)
someInstance = java_class.new_instance("Joe")
```

It uses Java reflection to instantiate `MyJavaClass`.

However, this can be done more simply without adding the class as ruby var. First, ensure the path of the folder of `MyJavaClass` is on the classpath ([or ruby `$LOAD_PATH`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/ClasspathAndLoadPath)).  Then, call the class as follows in `Test.rb`.

```
someInstance = Java::MyJavaClass.new("joe")
```

or

```
 java_import 'MyJavaClass'
 someInstance = MyJavaClass.new("Joe")
```