# Can a Ruby script in JRuby use my Java classes if I haven't shared them with it?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

If I have a `Ruby` script executed by `ScriptingContainer` of `JRuby` in my `Java` application, is the `Ruby` script capable of accessing or making use of a class I have defined in my `Java` application **if I haven't shared anything with the script**?

By sharing this is what I mean:

```
ruby = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
ruby.put("main", MyClass.class);
ruby.runScriptlet(readFile("Test.rb"));
```

As you can see, I am sharing with the `Ruby` script a variable called main, whose value is `MyClass.class`.

**If I don't share anything**, is the `Ruby` script still capable of using `MyClass` in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as per [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14226171/289466): if `MyClass` is on your classpath/`$LOAD_PATH`, JRuby will pick it up when you `java_import` it.

Comment: Ah, and it can't be avoided?

Comment: @Omega What do you want to avoid?  Putting the class on the classpath?

Comment: That despite having the classes on the classpath, avoid the java_import.

Comment: You must either use the `Java::` prefix or `java_import` as your class is in the "default" package, or put your class in a package that starts with either `org` or `com` and then refer to the class with its fully-qualified name.